# Get the Default Table Style of a Word Document (from VSTO add-in)

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

**Question:**
**How can I get the default table style for the document from a C# VSTO addin?**

Or its name, at least?

**Caveats:**

- Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.DefaultTableStyle doesn't work.
- Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML doesn't provide the answer.

**Long Story:**

When I create a template and assign my custom style (let's say, "MyStyle") to be the default table style, I can see that it works fine:

- new tables get created with that style
- if I unzip the template file and browse to ~\word\settings.xml , it's right there, plain as day:

  ```
  <w:settings (...)>
  (...)
   <w:defaultTabStop w:val="720"/>
   <w:defaultTableStyle w:val="MyStyleID"/>
   <w:characterSpacingControl w:val="doNotCompress"/>
  ```

HOWEVER, when I try to access the style from my (c#) vsto addin in a document created from this template, I can't access this information in any way.

- Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.DefaultTableStyle returns something I cannot seem to identify in any way. It seems to be a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style object, but its .LocalName property is empty and trying to access pretty much every other property throws an exception...
- and if I inspect Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.WordOpenXML property I get:

  ```
   <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/settings.xml" (...)>
    <pkg:xmlData>
     <w:settings (...)>
      (...)
      <w:defaultTabStop w:val="720"/>
      <w:characterSpacingControl w:val="doNotCompress"/>
  ```

... so the one bit I need is magically missing :/ . Of course I did a search throughout the WordOpenXML output for "MyStyleID" as well as its rsid and full name, but nothing indicates that it's the default style!

In fact, I can see this elsewhere:

```
<w:style w:type="table" w:default="1" w:styleId="TableNormal">
```

So the TableNormal style (on which MyStyle is based) is actually indicated as the default... but when I create tables, they do get MyStyle assigned, not TableNormal!

Somebody please advise...

Comment: Did you set the style “MyStyle” as the default table style for the current document or for *all* new document? I'm not able to repro; at least when I set my custom table style as the default table style for the current document, `ActiveDocument.DefaultTableStyle` contains that style. I'm on the latest Office 2016 version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please try to create a template out of the document, save it, then create a document out of the template (with a double-click or right-click > New) and see if you can see the DefaultTableStyle set there.